# How to efficiently retrieve rows with large JSON objects in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, relational-database

I've inherited the task of retrieving data from a Postgres table.
The table has ~1m rows, and there are about 145k rows that I wish to retrieve. These 145k rows have a common string in one of their columns `batch_name` that I can use to search for them.

The table has two columns `payload` & `result` that are of type `JSON`. The `result` column contains the data that I wish to retrieve.

When I make even the simplest queries to the table:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE batch_name = 'an_id' limit 10
```

The request takes ~7-10 seconds to return data.

This is despite the fact that the `batch_name` column has an index on it and it's of type `varchar(255)`

Whilst investigating this, I've discovered that the JSON objects in the `result` column and `payload` column can be absolutely gigantic objects. When prettified, they are sometimes ~27k lines long.

These gigantic JSON objects seem to be the root cause of the problem.
My questions are:

1. What can I do to improve the efficiency of this query? Or is the ultimate solution here to just modify the table such that we are no longer storing gigantic JSON objects?
2. Given that I don't need to actually query fields in these JSON objects (but I DO need to retrieve them), would simply storing them as strings improve efficiency?
3. Why is storing large JSON objects SO inefficient?

Thanks in advance for any help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: If you don't need to query the JSON, then don't select the column (i.e. don't use `select * ...`). But if you need to retrieve the content of the column, then there is not much you can do. It's not the storage that inefficient - retrieving many large values and sending them over the network will take some time. You didn't tell us how big those JSON values are but 27000 **lines** sounds as if they are multiple MB in size. Just think about the data that is transferred in that case, add some overhead of the network protocol and you know why this is slow.

Comment: If you want to make storing the data more efficient, then normalize your data model and ditch the JSON storage completely.

Comment: If you *don't need to actually query these JSON objects* just don't query them. It's likely that the question isn't about Postgres query efficiency but about sending enormous useless data over the net.

Comment: Step one when having performance issues is always EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for your query to get the query plan. Without it, know body knows what part of the query is time consuming. And when the query is fast, it can be something else, like network or application code.

Comment: And SELECT * is imho never useful in production and should be avoided.